# Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.4, pusher

i have created a chat app using pusher in laravel
but this types errors occurs in console when run application

1. WebSocket connection to 'wss://ws-your-pusher-app-cluster.pusher.com/app/your-pusher-key?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.1.0&flash=false' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
2. OPTIONS https://sockjs-your-pusher-app-cluster.pusher.com/pusher/app/your-pusher-key/150/ccc8teqg/xhr_streaming?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.1.0&t=1510723218799&n=1 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: and your question is ... ?

Comment: i have create chat app using pusher in laravel

Comment: when run app then this type of errors ocurs in console in chrome

Comment: and in firefox
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://ws-your-pusher-app-cluster.pusher.com/app/your-pusher-key?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.1.0&flash=false.

Comment: Yes. It says that above. That's still not a question

Comment: so how to solve this error?

Comment: what is the code that caused the error?

Comment: public/js/app.js 33022 show in console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159024/discussion-between-maulik-and-zazzle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` means the hostname cannot be resolved to an IP address by the DNS. If you look at the hostname `ws-your-pusher-app-cluster.pusher.com`, you can see that you should change the subdomain `ws-your-pusher-app-cluster` to whatever cluster your pusher app is located on. You can find the cluster in the Pusher dashboard.

Comment: i tried but now,
Pusher : Error : {"type":"WebSocketError","error":{"type":"PusherError","data":{"code":4005,"message":"Path not found"}}}
this type of error occurred